# How can I line up an equation with the equals sign from another equation?

Tags: align

I have the following code.

```
\begin{align*}
H([(1,0,0)], [(1,0,1)]) &= \min{}\{ &|(1 - 0) - (1 - 1)| + |(0 - 0) - (0 - 1)|, \\ 
&|(1 - 0) - (1 - 0)| + |(0 - 0) - (1 - 0)|, \\
&|(0 - 1) - (0 - 1)| + |(0 - 1) - (1 - 1)| \}
\end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
= \min{(2,1,1)} = 1
\end{equation*}
```

This produces an environment where my absolute values are nice and aligned exactly the way I want them, and one separate equation. Is there a way I can make the equals sign in the second equation line up with the equals sign in the `align` environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you want to nest `aligned`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
H([(1,0,0)], [(1,0,1)]) 
&= \min\{
     \begin{aligned}[t]
     &|(1 - 0) - (1 - 1)| + |(0 - 0) - (0 - 1)|, \\
     &|(1 - 0) - (1 - 0)| + |(0 - 0) - (1 - 0)|, \\
     &|(0 - 1) - (0 - 1)| + |(0 - 1) - (1 - 1)| \}
     \end{aligned}\\
&= \min\{2,1,1\} = 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Shouldn't `\lvert` and `\rvert` be used instead of `| |`?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, but in this case the simplified input is good.

Comment: I’m a bit confused. In which cases the simplified input produces the desired result?